# R sweave - stop tables from floating

Tags: floats, r, sweave

Please excuse my naive question:

I am using R studio sweave with xelatex and tinytex

I run this chunk to produce a table, but it is automatically printed on the last page, adding a huge blank space before.
How can I prevent it?

```
<<>>=

library(modelsummary)

datasummary_skim(mtcars,output="latex",histogram = F)

@
```

In the preamble I use the folowing packages

```
 \usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype{d}{S[input-symbols = ()]}
```

and

`options("modelsummary_format_numeric_latex" = "plain")`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when I add

```
\usepackage{float}
 \floatplacement{figure}{H}
  \floatplacement{table}{H}
```

the issue is solved.
I would be interested to know any other suitable approaches!